# ASP.NET/MVC: Automatic "validation-as-you-type"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, annotations, client-side-validation

EDIT: I got it working now for text fields (see the comments below the question).

However, for some reason, the validation doesn't kick in for my dropdown-list.

In my ViewModel I have this:

```
[Display(Name = "Country")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is definitely required!")]
public int CountryId { get; set; }
```

In my View I have this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CountryId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
     @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, Model.CountryList, "—Select a country --", 
      new { @class = "form-control" })
     <div class="container_voor_error">
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CountryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
     </div>
</div>
```

The code in the controller need not be given here I think, since it works fine: it fills the CountryList with the countries, and then later after submit it does the server-side validation and processing, no problem.

So the scenario is this:

- I select a country in the dropdown list (say, Belgium);
- Then I de-select that choice again, so that it shows “-- Select a country -- “ again;
- Now the (lazy) client-side validation should kick in and result in an error message: “Country is definitely required!”;
- But that doesn’t happen, no error message is shown.

So... Am I forgetting something, or doing something wrong?

END-OF-EDIT

An easy question for the MVC/ASP.NET experts, I suppose. But as I'm still finding my way in this framework (school courses), this is something I've been wondering about, and that I haven't found an explicit answer to.

It's about client side validation of form input, using annotations in my model (or viewmodel). I get that, as long as one or more of the annotated validation requirements are NOT satisfied, the values of the form fields are NOT sent to the server upon submit. Instead, the same form view is displayed again, this time with the applicable error message shown. That is, of course, assuming that an HTML helper for those error messages (like Html.ValidationMessageFor) is included with the form fields. So far, so good.

However, there's such a thing as "validation-as-you-type". Meaning that the error messages appear (and change) while the user is still typing, as opposed to appearing only on the re-loaded form after the user has hit submit. And this is my question: Is "validation-as-you-type" supposed to be operational automatically? Because that's what seems to be generally implied (though hardly explicitly stated) by internet sources/tutorials.

But my experience has been different: In order to have "validation-as-you-type", I always need to write JavaScript/jQuery event handlers (such as keyUp() and onChange()), in which I explicitly call

```
$('some-selector').validate().element('some-element');
```

So my question is: Is it normal that I have to make these explicit calls to method validate() for each to-be-validated form element? Or is there, in ASP.NET/MVC, a way to enable automatic "validation-as-you-type" for all elements (or perhaps a subset of elements) on a view form?

Thanks.

Comment: That is the default behavior if you have not disabled client side validation, and you have included the relevant scripts. And your misunderstanding how client side validation works - _the same form view is displayed again_ is wrong - when you click the submit button and there are validation errors, the form is never submitted or _displayed again_. And you do not need your `$('some-selector').validate().element('some-element');` code

Comment: @Stepen Muecke OK thanks, but I'm a bit confused here. On the one hand, you state that the described behaviour (i.e. NO "validation-as-you-type") is the default, but then you also state that I do not need the jajvaScript/jQuery line. But then how am I supposed to achieve the "validation-as-you-type"? 
(Or do you mean that "validation-as-you-type" IS in fact default behaviour?) 
Also, I'm working here with default settings: After scaffolding, I haven't enabled or disabled anything relevant, nor have I added or removed any relevant scripts.

Comment: Continued: 
Also, you state that with validation errors, the form "is never submitted or displayed again"... Right, you mean that nothing is posted to the server (i.e., no "POST" or "GET" action taking place), correct? Yes, I understand that, it's just simply the same page shown with the error messages added on the client-side (jS).

Comment: You need to include `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive` in your view and all this is handled correctly

Comment: And note that client side validation is lazy (meaning you can tab through controls without triggering validation). Once you enter an invalid value and tab out, the error message will be displayed. When you tab back in - from that point on - your value is validated in each keyup event

Comment: Am gonna try adding jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive in my view as soon as I can.

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK I added jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive. And it made a difference, just like you said. But it's still not real validation-as-you-type, and your last comment explains why: The FIRST TIME you start typing in a text field, it just doesn't happen. While I now understand from your comment why this is so, I still find it undesirable: From a user's perspective, it's just inconsistent that the validation-as-you-type doesn't happen the first time. What would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: Also, while it works for text fields, it doesn't work for my drop-down list. The model property corresponding to that drop-down list is also annotated as 'Required', but the error message never appears (i.e., when you first select an item, then de-select it back to the default 0 no-selection option "--- Select an item ---" at the top of the drop-down list). So I suppose for drop-down lists, and possibly other types of input fields, writing event handlers is a necessity. Many thanks, and if you could turn it into an answer, that also addresses my latest comments, I would accept it.

Comment: Of course it works for dropdownlists. And what do you mean the _the default 0 option_ - if you have created an option with `value="0"` then that would be valid (a `[Required]` attribute means just that - it cannot be `null` and `0` is not `null`. I suggest you need to spend some time learning the basics of MVC validation

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks again, your comment about lazy validation in particular was pure gold for me, otherwise I wouldn't have understood the observed behaviour at all (and I haven't seen this mentioned before). And after doing some reading about the jQuery (plug-in) validation, I even understand the reason behind it. Also, yes, you're of course technically correct that 0 does represents a drop-down selection, it's just that it does not represent a 'real' selection (i.e., an actual item) - whereas I would have expected a Required annotation to require such a 'real' selection. But I get it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136904/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-holland).

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I edited the question for the remaining issue with the dropdown-list (that we had a brief chat about yesterday). Can't stay at my computer right now unfortunately, but will come back tomorrow (i.e. in about 8 or 9 hours' time), and hope you can reply with a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, ASP.NET MVC does not offer Automatic "validation as you type". To have a "validation as you type" it must be javascript code. ASP.NET Mvc uses **jQuery Validation** plugin by default, and this plugin does validation on **blur** event, which is not the same as on **keyup** events.

All that ASP.NET MVC does, is render some html attributes to the elements, also known as unobtrusive validation. You can check this if you see the page source with validation enabled and then with disabled. Then there is a javscript library that uses the values in those attributes to hook up to proper events.

Lastly, one is also able to use different plugin/library for this, and also one is also able to change how ASP.NET emits validation to the client side.

Comment: `jquery.validate` does validate on `.keyup`! (refer the [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/), in particular the section titled _A few things to look out for when playing around with the demo_

Answer (score 0):

This is how you validate immediately. This works in ASP.NET Core. This validates immediately, not only after the first blur.

In `document.ready` (jquery), do this:

```
function CustomValidationMarco() {
  var validator = $("form").data("validator");
  if (validator) {
    //validator.settings.onkeyup = true; // disable validation on keyup

    validator.settings.onkeyup = function (element) {
      $(element).valid();
    };

    //validator.settings.onfocusout = function (element) {
    //  $(element).valid();
    //};

  }
}
```